# Setting start of week to monday - datefirst has no effect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider following script:

```
SET LANGUAGE 'German'
GO
SET DATEFIRST 1
GO

DECLARE @FullDate DATETIME
DECLARE @DayofWeek tinyint
DECLARE @relativeWeek int

SELECT @FullDate  = '5/1/2008'
WHILE (@FullDate <= '7/1/2008')
BEGIN

SELECT DATEPART (DW , @FullDate) as day_of_week, DATEDIFF(WEEK, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @FullDate) as relative_week

SELECT @FullDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Fulldate)
END
```

The result currently is

```
day_of_week   relative_week
----------------------------
6   -220
7   -219
1   -219
```

Now how do I manage to get the result like this:

```
day_of_week   relative_week
----------------------------
6   -220
7   -220 <-- here's the difference :) 
1   -219
```

Meaning to have the start of the week on monday / day 1 of week. As you can see setting the datefirst variable to 1 doesn't have an effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You two examples have the same results... so the answer is you get the 2nd result by doing nothing.

Comment: @Hogan: compare the results for day_of_week 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/8cc3493a-7ae5-4759-ab2a-e7683165320b/

Hope it helps.

As a fact - DATEDIFF doesn't care about DATEFIRST